# How to Update Identity Column on .Net Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, identity-column

I have a question,
how to update an identity column on sql server db using EF in net core 3.0.
on net core 2.0 i can use

```
.UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()
.Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior
```

but in net core 3.0 i can't use that method again, 
can you tell me what method can i use for update identity column on database in net core 3.0

Comment: Try `var prop = modelBuilder.Entity<YourModel>().Property(p => p.Id); prop.UseIdentityColumn(); prop.Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);` ?

Answer (score 0):

For each entity on save new record you can use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

or for every save changes get new Id

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
```

value generated by sql server and work on EF Core 2+

by default Id columns are identity but you can use meta data on other property

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int IdSecondary { get; set; }
```